# How to display sub view or button on top of Google maps Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, google-maps, swift2

I was trying to add a button on top of Google maps. i tried everything i could but no help can anyone help me.. in Xcode preview it shows on top but after running the app it come below google map.

> Picture after running app

[image: Picture after running app]

> How it looks in XCODE

[image: How it looks in XCODE]

> CODE OF MAP

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class HomeViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBAction func refreshLocation(sender: AnyObject) {
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    }
@IBOutlet weak var gMapView: GMSMapView!


let locationManager = CLLocationManager()




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
  locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    self.scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320, 700)


            let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(15.4989, longitude: 73.8278, zoom: 17)

            gMapView.camera = camera
            gMapView.myLocationEnabled = true

            self.view.addSubview(gMapView)
            let marker = GMSMarker()

            marker.map = self.gMapView

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

}

extension HomeViewController {
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if status == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedAlways {
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        gMapView.myLocationEnabled = true

        gMapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
    }
}
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if let location = locations.first {
        gMapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: location.coordinate, zoom: 15, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)

        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

    }
}



}
```

Comment: Also, share the code if you are manipulating subviews programmatically. Information about the constraints will also be helpful.

Comment: i am doing everything using auto layout. nothing programmatically. i'm new to iOS

Comment: Yes I can see you are using autolayout. Share the code where you are creating the map. Also tell us which constraints are you using on control.png (Which is the Imageview you want to bring to top, I assume). Also, a UIImageView is not a UIButton.

Comment: i have updated the code

Comment: One needs to add the subviews before assinging view=mapView.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the answer

```
self.view.bringSubviewToFront(self.view_name)
```

You need to call bringSubviewToFront on the parent view.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using below method? If yes , make sure you are giving frame to mapview so try to give frame as same as you gave in storyboard.

[GMSMapView mapWithFrame:(CGRect) camera:(GMSCameraPosition *)];

Comment: actually i'm using swift and i'm using this 

gMapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: location.coordinate, zoom: 15, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)

Comment: @O-mkar What Frame are you giving the MapView?

Comment: if you are not using that method , no need to give frame.

Comment: Okay , try to solve using by giving frame to gMapView. give frame before you use syntax addSubview or gave outlet gMapView , so no need to use addSubview method